# calculating average of random integers in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to generate a specified number of random integers between any
two values specified by the user (example, 12 numbers all between 10 and 20), and then calculate the average of the numbers. 
The problem is if I ask for it to generate 10 numbers, it will only generate 9 (shown in output.) 
Also, if I enter a max range of 100 and min range of 90, the program will still generate #'s like 147, etc that are over the max range... did I mess up the random number generator? Can someone help?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class ArrayRandom
{
static Console c;           // The output console

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    c = new Console ();
    DecimalFormat y = new DecimalFormat ("###.##");

    c.println ("How many integers would you like to generate?");
    int n = c.readInt (); 
    c.println ("What is the maximum value for these numbers?");
    int max = c.readInt ();
    c.println ("What is the minimum value for these numbers?");
    int min = c.readInt ();

    int numbers[] = new int [n]; 
    int x;
    double sum = 0; 
    double average = 0; 

    //n = number of random integers generated
    for (x = 1 ; x <= n-1 ; x++) 
    {

        numbers [x] = (int) (max * Math.random () + min); 
    }

    for (x = 1 ; x <= n-1 ; x++) 
    {
        sum += numbers [x]; 
        average = sum / n-1); 

    }

    c.println ("The sum of the numbers is: " + sum); 
    c.println ("The average of the numbers is: " + y.format(average)); 

    c.println ("Here are all the numbers:"); 
    for (x = 1 ; x <= n-1 ; x++)  
{
        c.println (numbers [x]); //print all numbers in array
}


} // main method
} // ArrayRandom class
```

Comment: Did you edit your code to the corrected version? Please don't — it makes it harder for those reading the question (after it's been solved) to see what the problem was.

Comment: Oh okay, sorrry! I will go back to the original version.

Answer (score 3):

Java arrays are zero based. Here you leave the first array element at its default value of `0`. Replace

```
for (x = 1 ; x <= n-1 ; x++)
```

with

```
for (x = 0 ; x < n ; x++)
```

---

*Edit:* To answer question (from now deleted comment) of why this does not produce values between min and max

```
max * Math.random () + min
```

[Math.random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) generates double values between `0.0` and `1.0`. So for example, a min of `90` and max of `100` would generate numbers between and `90` and `190`(!). To limit the values between the min and max you would need

```
min + Math.random() * (max - min)
 ^    |_________________________|                          
 |                 |
90       value between 0 - 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Java arrays start indexing at 0.  Also your loop is exiting one index short.  So, when n==6, your condition is then, "x <=5", and the loop exits.  Try this:

```
for ( x = 0; x < n; x++ {
   // stuff
}
```